# Opening web project set to IIS directory in machine without IIS, pointing to embedded server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, tfs

I can open a web project in TFS; however, in my QA environment I have to change it to use IIS.  In my local dev environment, I don't have IIS and can't install it.

New company rules deny access in QA to me and I can't open my web project to fix it in my machine.

When I open the project I receive "The Web Application Project ... is configured to use IIS. To access local IIS Web sites, you must run Visual Studio in the context of an administrator account." Then I open as administrator but VS asks for the virtual directory to be creatred on my IIS.

Answer (score 6):

The NgM link can really help, but if you need a step-by-step way than go to your .csproj file property. Make it writable, open it in a text editor and search for `<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>` turn it to `<UseIIS>False</UseIIS>`. Open solution, get the latest version and when you receive a warning, keep the local version of your modified .csproj. You can too check-in your modified .csproj to stop troubles in the next latest version.

bye

Comment: Wow hah, not sure why I put grammer. I always spell it correctly, thanks though. :)