# simple approval system in windows workflow

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I want to generate simple document approval system in workflow foundation. We have already available document approval process example on `MSDN` but it is quite complex to understand as it involves `WCf` and all. I just want a startup with workflow foundation so it's better if I follow step by step guide tutorial. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a blog post on how to implement a simple approval workflow using emails and ASP.Net MVC.

http://blog.petegoo.com/index.php/2010/08/22/workflow-4-email-approval-sample/

Comment: your sample required IIS configuration so i m not able to open all projects.i wanna implement same using Asp.Net if you can help out to develop the same,i would be grateful to you.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550129/opening-web-project-set-to-iis-directory-in-machine-without-iis-pointing-to-emb

Comment: thanks Peter Goodman.i am able to open up your project now.thanks man.i can refer your project now to make my app using asp.net.i would like to know any links for that if you have. actually i want links showing integration of asp.net and WF.thanks

Comment: Sorry, you're going to have to google that stuff. There's nothing much specific on integrating WF with ASP.Net but it's not difficult. Passing an array to an activity? Just specify the type in your argument/receive parameter as an array and when you call it, pass an array

Comment: Peter Goodman i have designed application according to yours but not working. how to run the application u developed ? please help. My application send all mails on mentioned mail id in the array but what the later process not working properly. mvc application needs to be hosted on IIS ? when i click on the link of approve and decline it gives me an error.

Comment: Please contact me at my blog rather than filling up the comments here. Send me the full error info

Answer (score 2):

I think http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7fe6f504-a58d-456e-8f55-e64bddc81a41 is a good tutorial to start with. It is better if you try this with state machine type of workflow because you need several user inputs from outside the workflow in several stages.